# Which SATA port to use for Intel SSD with Dell Optiplex 990?

Tags: ssd, sata, dell-optiplex

I just bought an Intel 520 Series SSD and I have 4 SATA ports on my Dell Optiplex 990. SATA0 - dark blue, SATA1 - black and SATA2 and SATA3 - white. On the datasheet of Dell Optiplex 990 I can not see which of those 4 ports are SATA 2 and which are SATA 3 for my SSD.

Anyone could help me? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try asking Dell?

Comment: Just use the port you are already using for your storage device.  Use the SATA3 port.

Comment: I asked Dell, I am waiting for response there too

Answer (score 3):

The user manual for your pc can be found here:
ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-990_Service%20Manual4_en-us.pdf

With most motherboards you should always work from port 1 so on, but it really doesn't matter unless they are different speeds and you want peak performance. For example my asus mother board has 4 ports, two sata 6gbps and two sata 3gbps.. I would want to use my 6gbps ports first before using my 3gbps ports. I believe the colours is use to highlight port one.

If the other ports are all the same colour I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 2):

In a Mini-tower, Use the two SATA ports that are not white. It appears the white ones are the SATA2 ports. Just found this out via some trial and error testing with a new SSD.